# Разбор строки под array

Tags: php

```
Хочу разобрать строку под array
Строка вида 1,0,1,1,0,1
Хочу получить типа вывода каждого значения в переменную
Вывод:
echo $num['5'];
Результат: 0
```

Comment: @Креатив-Сервис Ремонт-Пк, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

----------

P.S. 

    echo $num['5'];

Результат: 1 )))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужна ф-ция [explode](http://www.php.su/functions/?explode)

Comment: Точняк Спасибо